# iOS style buttons on the mac

Tags: objective-c, xcode, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to recreate the look here:

[image]

(Except normally these buttons would not be disabled). How do I recreate this iOS-style look in an objective-C application?

Comment: It really should be just as simple as creating a button that has two states when you click on it, or implementing a click event to slide it from left to right as you drag.

Comment: I've tried to find a framework that would implement this functionality for me, but I couldn't find one. I know it's a radio button with a custom view but I'm not sure how to implement it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Mondo Switch](http://mcormier.github.com/CocoaMondoKit/) seems like a good place to start